# Metoer Score As Metric for Training

Tags: huggingface-transformers

How to use meteor score as evaluation metrics, I mean deciding to stop training if meteor score stops increasing.

The main issue that I face , meteor score need (ref, pred) as list of words. So, after each epoch I need to convert predicted tokens back to words, to use it.

But the main issue is that tokenizer don't accept tensor . I also can't convert tensor to numpy array while training.

Pls suggest some method so that I can use meteor in place of accuracy as metric while training.

Thank you in advance